# 32 and 64 bit usage

Tags: pi-4, electron

My raspberry Pi 4 reports with `uname -m` armv7l

I understand that it was a business decision here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=245846 to do so and not go for arm64

However when building an electron-build with either  “x64” | “ia32” | “armv7l” | “arm64” (https://www.electron.build/cli#targetconfiguration)

my assumption is to take (as electron-build parameters) armv7l for e.g. raspbian32 and arm64 for raspbian64 , is this assumption correct?

Comment: `armv7l` is 32-bit (specifically for the BCM2711). `aarch64` is 64-bit. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/README.md